# Is this a bad way to create a list-filter method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this binding on my page. The page shows a table of items. Each row has a `data-navn` attribute set to the same as the first column, only all lower case. This list can be quite long, so I wanted to create some sort of filtering to it. I created a textbox, and attached this eventhandler to it.

Is this a nice way to do this? It seems kind of hacky :)

```
    $("#filter").bind('keyup', function () {
        var t = $("#filter").val();
        if (t == "") {
            $(".row").show();
        } else {
            $(".row").hide();
            $('.row[data-navn*="' + t + '"]').show();
        }
    });
```

(I already had jQuery going on this page.)

Comment: That looks fine to me, however I would have used `.filter` instead of the attribute selector so that it will also find rows with data attributes that were set using jQuery's `.data()` method.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow... The data-navn attribute of the tr is set on page generation only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is brute force, but if the lists are small enough that it works efficiently then I think it is fine. If you start to find that performance lags then there are some optimizations you could consider. These are what I can think of off the top of my head.

1. Wait until at least two or three characters have been typed before filtering
2. Cache a list of current shown/hidden items so that jQuery doesn't do a full lookup on every pass.

Comment: The list will never by very long. 10-20 entries at max.